# What tools are better to create a mobile app with a db, buttons, forms

Tags: android, database

I'm a noob self learning programmer and i'm wondering how can i make an application for mobile. As an example, so you can understand what i need (and easier for me to explain), think of an application where the user can store products and related information by filling forms (an icon, price, name, features, weight...) and then consult stored information.

For me it looks like the best way to create it is by using web related tools like HTML, CSS, MySQL...

The problem i find is that i don't know how to create a web shaped application and then turn it into a mobile app.

I'm sorry if i didn't explain the best way, but hope you guys get my point are able to put me in the right way!

Thanks a lot in advance!!

P.S. Beyond HTML and CSS and a little MySQL i have basic knowledge of JS, C++ and C#.

Comment: If you want to use web based technology and you are having angular Js experience then you can use ionic framework to develop mobile app.Or else you can use android studio with sqlite database for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a newbie, it's better to do the correct choice at the beginning.

For Android development, the entry point is the developer portal: https://developer.android.com/

The app you've thinking of is quite classic: You won't have troubles to find some tutorials on the web.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with either SQLite or Firebase Realtime Database, you choose.

Comment: And Thanks to you too!!

Answer (score 1):

I guess, the easiest way will be creating responsive website and then include that in your app as a WebView. However, this might give users the feel that you're just loading the website in a WebView if you don't include some features like, maybe, push notifications, update checker, theme changer, something like that.

You can alos find a lot of easy tutorials and templates to build a WebView app.

P.S.: I myself have made an Android app of my friend's blog by first making a website and then using WebViews.